# AJAX - Can I reference a method from the controller by url?

Tags: controller, ajax, url, method

I am wondering if I can use the standard $.ajax, $.post or $.get with visual force. If so what do I put in the url? Can I get the url of the method I want to make a call to?

Comment: There's [this](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/apex_ajax.pdf)

Comment: If you want to access a method in the controller though, why not use javascript remoting?

Comment: check this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104026/rest-api-post-method-with-jquery

Comment: @martin because I don't think I can access attributes like xhr with remote actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this post [Rest API (POST method) with Jquery](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104026/rest-api-post-method-with-jquery)

**GET, POST AND DELETE Method using Jquery**

You can use stndard services or You can create own rest service and use in jquery

If you want callout to other org then in header you need to pass userName, password and security token

```
<apex:page>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div>
        <input  class="btn" value="Get Account list" type="button" onclick="getSobjectList()" />
        <input  class="btn" value="Create Account Record" type="button" onclick="createSobjectRecord()" />
        <input class="btn" value="Delete Account Record" type="button" onclick="deleteSobjectRecord()" />
    </div>
    <div id="warehouseList">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        var sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
        function getSobjectList() {
            $j.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/services/data/v35.0/query?q="+''+"{!URLENCODE('SELECT Id, Name FROM Account')}",
                headers: {"Authorization" : "OAuth " + sessionId},
                crossDomain : true,
                dataType: 'application/json',
                success: function (responseData) {
                    console.log(responseData);
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    console.log(request.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
        var recordId;
        function createSobjectRecord() {
             var accountInfo = { "Name" :"Testing Jquery with Rest"};
             var accountInfoJson = JSON.stringify(accountInfo);
             $j.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/services/data/v35.0/sobjects/Account",
                headers : {
                        'Authorization' : "OAuth " + sessionId,
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                  },
                crossDomain : true,
                data: JSON.stringify(accountInfo),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (responseData, status, xhr) {
                    console.log(responseData.id);
                    recordId = responseData.id;
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    console.log(request.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
        function deleteSobjectRecord(){
            $j.ajax({
                type: "Delete",
                url: "/services/data/v35.0/sobjects/Account/"+recordId,
                headers : {
                        'Authorization' : "OAuth " + sessionId,
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                  },
                crossDomain : true,
                success: function (responseData, status, xhr) {
                    console.log(responseData);
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    console.log(request.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```